# Will lipid molecules 'flip-flop' over a membrane without the use of an enzyme?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

All of the references to this I can find refer to enzymes like Flippase making it 'easier' or 'more likely' that the translocation will occur, rather than actually make it possible.

The following is from Alberts

> In the ER, however, phospholipids equilibrate across the membrane within minutes, which is almost 100,000 times faster than can be accounted for by spontaneous “flip-flop.”

Does this mean that left unattended, any phospholipid membrane will 'flip-flop' spontaneously, just very slowly, and can this be observed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bilayer components will 'flip-flop' at measurable rates, but these are very different for different lipid classes. Here are the results of an experiment using fluorescently-labelled analogues.

> Bai, JN and Pagano, RE (1997) Measurement of spontaneous transfer and transbilayer movement of BODIPY-labeled lipids in lipid vesicles. Biochemistry 36:8840-8848 [DOI: 10.1021/bi970145r](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/bi970145r)

The authors followed the transbilayer (flip-flop) and interbilayer movement of fluorescently-labelled analogues of various membrane lipids: sphingomyelin (C-5-DMB-SM), ceramide (C-5-DMB-Cer), phosphatidylcholine (C-5-DMB-PC) and diacylglycerol (C-5-DMB-DAG) in a system of unilamellar vesicles consisting of 1-palmitoyl-2-oleoyl phosphatidylcholine.

The results were analysed in terms of a model in which the labelled molecules could move between vesicles and between the two monolayers of the bilayer.

```
half times:
            interbilayer    transbilayer (flip-flop)
C-5-DMB-SM  >21 s           3.3 h               
C-5-DMB-Cer 350 s           22 min
C-5-DMB-PC  400 s           7.5 h
C-5-DMB-DAG 100 h           70 ms
```

So, for the phospholipid tested the half-time for flip-flop was 7.5 hours.

Comment: This answer is a good starting point and gives a flavor of the issue. I think it's worth noting though that there is a pretty big variation between different experiments on flip-flop rates. I think there are orders of magnitude changes, and so a more recent reference would be good. (Anyone interested in this could probably look at the 1997 ref. and see what papers cite it in Google Scholar.)